# VBA Combobox and Listbox common superclass

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a function for excel-VBA. This function is used to calculate the index of a certain string in a combobox or listbox. I would like the function to have the following signature:

```
Public Function MyIndexOf(list As ???, str As String) As Integer
```

My question is if there is a common superclass to Combobox and Listbox so i can replace ??? with some class.

Maybe there is another way of doing IndexOf. Suggestions are welcome but i want it to be done in a common separate function.

Anyone have a suggestion on how to solve this?

Thanks in advance
/Patrik

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no inheritance in VBA (or VB 6), so unfortunately there's no such thing as a superclass.

You do, however, have the benefit of very loose typing. You can declare the variable as a `Variant`, which is a universal data type that can hold any type of value, including a control. Generally, you should try and *avoid* using the `Variant` type if at all possible, but in this case, you have little choice.

So you could declare your function like this:

```
Public Function MyIndexOf(list As Variant, str As String) As Integer
    ' Do work here...
End Function
```

Of course, remembering that a `Variant` data type can really hold *any* type of value, and that the type is not known until run-time, a good defensive programmer would check to make sure that the specified type is not an `Integer` or a `String` or even a control that doesn't expose the same public members as a `ComboBox` or `ListBox` control (thus breaking the code you wrote expecting one that does).

You can determine the actual type of a `Variant` at runtime using the `TypeName` function. So you could simply modify the above function to include a guard clause to protect against anything other than a `ComboBox` or `ListBox` control being passed in:

```
Public Function MyIndexOf(list As Variant, str As String) As Integer
    If (Not TypeName(list) = "ComboBox") And (Not TypeName(list) = "ListBox") Then
        MsgBox "Wrong type of list variable was specified."
    Else
        ' Do work here...
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Do you not mean `TypeName(list)`?

Comment: @Geoffrey: Of course I do; good catch. I guess you can tell what I'd name that variable. It's fixed.

Comment: Alternative; Function p(ctrl As MSForms.Control)
If TypeOf ctrl Is MSForms.ComboBox then .. ElseIf TypeOf ctrl Is MSForms.ListBox then..

Comment: I agree that `MSForms.Control` is much better than `Variant`. Even `list As Object` would be better than `As Variant`. You want as narrow a type as possible. `Variant` is the broadest conceivable type; it can be absolutely anything: a primitive, an array, etc.